I would like to know how can I correct the mistakes in this plot
I need some help to correct my plot in Latex (overleaf). as you can see int eh photo attached I was not able to move the left Ylable more to the left. I addition the legend are overlapping.
I would like to know that is necessary to adjust to make it corect.
I have the following code to plot it:
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.8\textwidth, % Largura do gráfico
            height=0.5\textwidth, % Altura do gráfico
            xlabel={Pressão [bar]},
            ylabel={Hidrogênio líquido produzido},
            y axis line style={left},
            yticklabel style={anchor=east},
            ymin=0.035, ymax=0.185, % Ajuste dos limites do eixo y esquerdo
            grid=both, % Adiciona uma grade
            major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
            minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!20},
            minor tick num=5, % Número de subdivisões entre os ticks maiores
            mark options={solid},
            legend pos=north west, % Posição da legenda
            legend style={legend columns=1, at={(0.5,1.1)}, anchor=south,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}
        ]
        \addplot[
            color=blue,
            mark=square*,
        ] coordinates {
            (50, 0.035551519)
            (60, 0.041166795)
            (70, 0.046121908)
            (80, 0.05047213)
            (90, 0.054095171)
            (100, 0.057246878)
            (110, 0.059835302)
            (120, 0.061882869)
            (130, 0.063416394)
            (140, 0.064460956)
            (150, 0.065045596)
        };
        \addplot[
            color=red,
            mark=triangle*,
        ] coordinates {
            (50, 0.104992292)
            (60, 0.121957555)
            (70, 0.135526727)
            (80, 0.147589724)
            (90, 0.157573508)
            (100, 0.165603516)
            (110, 0.171836695)
            (120, 0.177620428)
            (130, 0.179637224)
            (140, 0.18150934)
            (150, 0.182283426)
        };
        \addlegendentry{LH2 com CH4}
        \addlegendentry{LH2 com N2}
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.8\textwidth, % Largura do gráfico
            height=0.5\textwidth, % Altura do gráfico
            xlabel={Pressão [bar]},
            ylabel={$SEC$ [kWh/kg]},
            ylabel near ticks,
            yticklabel pos=right,
            axis y line*=right,
            axis x line=none,
            yticklabel style={anchor=west},
            ymin=75, ymax=125, % Ajuste dos limites do eixo y direito
            legend pos=north east, % Posição da legenda
            legend style={legend columns=1, at={(0.5,1.1)}, anchor=south,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}
        ]
        \addplot[
            color=blue,
            mark=*,
            style=dashed,
        ] coordinates {
            (50, 121.7384542)
            (60, 114.2819522)
            (70, 109.2782737)
            (80, 105.8620381)
            (90, 103.8460745)
            (100, 102.5410077)
            (110, 101.9907997)
            (120, 102.0871085)
            (130, 102.7571192)
            (140, 103.9602337)
            (150, 105.6720593)
        };
        \addlegendentry{$SEC$ CH4}
        \addplot[
            color=red,
            mark=diamond*,
            style=dashed,
        ] coordinates {
            (50, 81.69341506)
            (60, 79.10337997)
            (70, 77.81112536)
            (80, 76.92253502)
            (90, 76.48783358)
            (100, 76.4056485)
            (110, 76.60867226)
            (120, 76.82040142)
            (130, 77.69422934)
            (140, 78.54201881)
            (150, 79.53379986)
        };
        \addlegendentry{$SEC$ N2}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Consumo energético e produção de hidrogênio líquido para os fluidos refrigerantes N2 e CH4 em diferentes pressões de operação.}
    \label{fig:pressao_sec}
\end{figure}

The output that I have is the following:


Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code to make it compilable? It should start  with \documentclass and end with \end{document}.

Looks like you overdetermined the legend positions. Here is a kind of demo, using two different approaches to separate the legend (no idea, how you'd like to have them).
Common to both: disabled %    legend pos= north east, % Posição da legenda
First legend: puts south at (.2,1.1), which may be hard to position; using south west as reference point should work with (0,1.1) to place it leftmost
  legend style={legend columns=1, at={(0.2,1.1)}, 
         anchor=south,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}

Second legend: uses aboves alternative approach by positioning its south east corner
            legend style={
            legend columns=1, 
            at={(1,1.1)}, 
            anchor=south east,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
            }


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.8\textwidth, % Largura do gráfico
            height=0.5\textwidth, % Altura do gráfico
            xlabel={Pressão [bar]},
            ylabel={Hidrogênio líquido produzido},
            y axis line style={left},
            yticklabel style={anchor=east},
            ymin=0.035, ymax=0.185, % Ajuste dos limites do eixo y esquerdo
            grid=both, % Adiciona uma grade
            major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
            minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!20},
            minor tick num=5, % Número de subdivisões entre os ticks maiores
            mark options={solid},
%            legend pos=north west, % Posição da legenda
            legend style={legend columns=1, at={(0.2,1.1)}, anchor=south,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}
        ]
        \addplot[
            color=blue,
            mark=square*,
        ] coordinates {
            (50, 0.035551519)
            (60, 0.041166795)
            (70, 0.046121908)
            (80, 0.05047213)
            (90, 0.054095171)
            (100, 0.057246878)
            (110, 0.059835302)
            (120, 0.061882869)
            (130, 0.063416394)
            (140, 0.064460956)
            (150, 0.065045596)
        };
        \addplot[
            color=red,
            mark=triangle*,
        ] coordinates {
            (50, 0.104992292)
            (60, 0.121957555)
            (70, 0.135526727)
            (80, 0.147589724)
            (90, 0.157573508)
            (100, 0.165603516)
            (110, 0.171836695)
            (120, 0.177620428)
            (130, 0.179637224)
            (140, 0.18150934)
            (150, 0.182283426)
        };
        \addlegendentry{LH2 com CH4}
        \addlegendentry{LH2 com N2}
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.8\textwidth, % Largura do gráfico
            height=0.5\textwidth, % Altura do gráfico
            xlabel={Pressão [bar]},
            ylabel={$SEC$ [kWh/kg]},
            ylabel near ticks,
            yticklabel pos=right,
            axis y line*=right,
            axis x line=none,
            yticklabel style={anchor=west},
            ymin=75, ymax=125, % Ajuste dos limites do eixo y direito
%            legend pos= north east, % Posição da legenda
            legend style={
            legend columns=1, 
            at={(1,1.1)}, 
            anchor=south east,/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}
            }
        ]
        \addplot[
            color=blue,
            mark=*,
            style=dashed,
        ] coordinates {
            (50, 121.7384542)
            (60, 114.2819522)
            (70, 109.2782737)
            (80, 105.8620381)
            (90, 103.8460745)
            (100, 102.5410077)
            (110, 101.9907997)
            (120, 102.0871085)
            (130, 102.7571192)
            (140, 103.9602337)
            (150, 105.6720593)
        };
        \addlegendentry{$SEC$ CH4}
        \addplot[
            color=red,
            mark=diamond*,
            style=dashed,
        ] coordinates {
            (50, 81.69341506)
            (60, 79.10337997)
            (70, 77.81112536)
            (80, 76.92253502)
            (90, 76.48783358)
            (100, 76.4056485)
            (110, 76.60867226)
            (120, 76.82040142)
            (130, 77.69422934)
            (140, 78.54201881)
            (150, 79.53379986)
        };
        \addlegendentry{$SEC$ N2}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Consumo energético e produção de hidrogênio líquido para os fluidos refrigerantes N2 e CH4 em diferentes pressões de operação.}
    \label{fig:pressao_sec}
\end{figure}

 
\end{document}

P.S.: At the moment there is a slight mismatch between the ticks for the secondary and primary y-scales. Perhaps you need some tweeking wrt min, max, i.e. ranges.

Thank you very much for the explination. It was exactly what I was looking for.
Regarding the Y axis (in the left), is it possible to move is more to the left, so I can see clearly the numbers in the Y axis.

Thank you. // The usual way seems to be setting xlabel absolut; see e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=pgfplots+label+distance . // However, with two axes involved it may be more useful to a) delete the left ylabel from the axis, b) put anode AFTER \end{axis} like \node[rotate=90,anchor=south] at (-1.5,2) {Hidrogênio líquido produzido};  // You may also have a look at ch. "4.19 Alignment Options" in https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-alignment to relate it to inner or outer boxes.
